# Hive window function : assigning group id to overlapping group

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

My data in a hive table is like below with id , start_time and end_time as string

```
id   start_time   end_time
101  10:00        12:00
101  10:15        12:30
101  12:15        12:45
101  13:00        14:00
102  10:15        10:30
```

I want to create a new field group_id which identifies records within each "id" that have overlapping start_time and end_time intervals. 
Desired Output is:

```
id   start_time   end_time group_id
101  10:00        12:00     1
101  10:15        12:30     1
101  12:15        12:45     1
101  13:00        14:00     2
102  10:15        10:30     3
```

For eg: within 101, 1st 3 records are overlapping:
2nd overlaps with 1st as 10:15 (start_time of 2st) is in between 10:00 & 12:00(start & end time of 1st).
3rd overlaps with 2nd as 12:15 (start_time of 3rd) is in between 10:15 & 12:30(start & end time of 2nd).
4th record doesn't overlap so it is assigned next group id (2).
last record is with different id and alone in the group so it is given the next id (3)

I tried to compare a record with its previous to check if its overlapping using lag function:

```
select id, start_time,end_time,
    case when rownum_per_id = 1 THEN 'TRUE'
         when start_time between lag(start_time,1) over w and lag(end_time,1) over w THEN 'TRUE'
         ELSE 'FALSE' END as overlap_ind
from 
    (select id,start_time,end_time,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by start_time) as rownum_per_id
     from (select id,
             from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_time,"HH:mm")) as start_time,
             from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(end_time,"HH:mm")) as end_time
           from test_table
         ) a
    ) b
window w as (partition by id order by start_time)
```

getting output as:

```
id  start_time          end_time            overlap_ind
101 1970-01-01 10:00:00 1970-01-01 12:00:00 TRUE
101 1970-01-01 10:15:00 1970-01-01 12:30:00 TRUE
101 1970-01-01 12:15:00 1970-01-01 12:45:00 TRUE
101 1970-01-01 13:00:00 1970-01-01 14:00:00 FALSE
102 1970-01-01 10:15:00 1970-01-01 10:30:00 TRUE
```

However not able to figure out the next step to assign incrementing group_id

Answer (score 0):

You can just use string operations for this.  One method is to calculate the cumulative max *before* each time.  Use that information to determine when a group begins -- then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_end_time >= start_time then 0
                else 1 end) over (partition by id order by start_time) as group_id
from (select t.*,
             max(end_time) over (partition by id order by start_time rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end_time
      from finance_acturl_data_smith.test_table t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

The above produces a separate `group_id` for each user.  We can adjust this by removing the `partition by`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_end_time >= start_time then 0
                else 1 end) over (order by id, start_time) as group_id
from (select t.*,
             max(end_time) over (partition by id order by start_time rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end_time
      from finance_acturl_data_smith.test_table t
     ) t;
```

This works because the first `partition by` is still used to define `prev_end_time`, so the first value for each `id` is `NULL` and goes to the `else`.

Comment: The inner query is giving a syntax error in Hive: SemanticException End of a WindowFrame cannot be UNBOUNDED PRECEDING (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: @Shanil . . . Not only is this standard SQL but Hive does explicitly support it:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics.